# "Outcome" Vs "Result"

Tags: word-choice

Suppose after a meeting among a company's board of directors, a member who missed the session and arrives e.g. one hour later, asks one of the presented members:

> - What was the meeting outcome?

and the second person answers:

> - The outcome was somewhat acceptable.

I need to know if it's possible to use "result" instead of "outcome' here or not?